# C# StackExchange.Redis How To subscribe by integer type key?

Tags: c#, redis

I want to set key value pair. But key type is string. 
How to enter integer key?

```
        ConfigurationOptions co = new ConfigurationOptions();
        co.EndPoints.Add("xxx:6379");

        ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(co);
        IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
        string value = "abcdefg";
        db.StringSet("TestStringKey", value);
        var value2 = db.StringGet("TestStringKey");
        this.Text=(value2);
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have integer _keys_ in Redis. [Their introduction to keys](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-keys) recommend having prefixes/schema anyway, so that's difficult to make to work with integers.

Comment: thank you. so do not enter key as integer.